# Merge pdf files and do page formatting using R or SAS

Tags: r, pdf, sas, pdflatex

I have around 10000 pdf files in which i have to do page and text formatting like add margins to page, convert all the text to particular font and size,etc and merge the files.

I searched a lot on google but could not find anything.

Please if someone can help with any option in R or SAS to perform this task.

Comment: For most of my PDF jobs I use `PDFjam` which is a command line tool for Linux I guess it is also available on Windows and Mac. So not a real R solution, but most of the stuff can be done there.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to do this in R and/or SAS?

Comment: @HongOoi: its a repetitive task which is required to be done almost every week. Is there any way to automate this. I preferred R or SAS as I know these softwares only

Comment: Yes. Use something designed for the job.

Comment: Adobe Professional will allow you to script these types of tasks. It has a tool builder to implement commands via a build-task approach or you can write custom javascript to accomplish these tasks. Document management is outside the scope of SAS/R. If SAS/R are generating these files in the first place, then I would suggest changing the process.